# Send 32bit word via SPI from Arduino

Tags: arduino, spi, serial-communication

I need to send a 32bit message from an arduino to an SPI device.
Could someone please help me how to do this? For example I want to send 255 (11111111 in binary) to channel 4. I thought I could send 111111110000000000000000 via SDI but I think I will need to send something like for example "0x040000f7". I honestly have no clue how I could convert the data I have to 32bit data...

[image: datasheet]

```
#include <SPI.h>
byte val;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT); //set SS pin as output
  SPI.begin(); // initialize SPI library

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  val == 00000000000000000000000000000000;
  digitalWrite(10, LOW); //set SS pin low to start communication
  SPI.transfer(val);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  delay(3000);

  val == 00000000000000000000000001000001;
  digitalWrite(10, LOW); //set SS pin low to start communication
  SPI.transfer(val);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  delay(3000);

  
}
```

Comment: Check the specification of the destination. Which of higher or lower byte should be transferred first?

Comment: I suppose you mean this:
Gain Byte Format is MSB First, Straight Binary
0 is the least Significant Bit of the channel Gain Byte
7 is the most Significant Bit of the channel Gain Byte
?

Comment: It looks like you don't need 32-bit word like "0x040000f7". Simply sending (and receiving) each bytes for channel 4 to channel 1 (in this order) should be enough.

Comment: Do you have some kind of example how to do this by any chance? Really new to this..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't need 32-bit data like "0x040000f7" and instead you should simply send data for each channels.

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
byte ch4, ch3, ch2, ch1;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT); //set SS pin as output
  SPI.begin(); // initialize SPI library
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  // set values to send
  ch4 = 255;
  ch3 = 128;
  ch2 = 64;
  ch1 = 32;
  digitalWrite(10, LOW); //set SS pin low to start communication
  // send values
  SPI.transfer(ch4); // Channel 4
  SPI.transfer(ch3); // Channel 3
  SPI.transfer(ch2); // Channel 2
  SPI.transfer(ch1); // Channel 1
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  delay(3000);
}
```